# Spring Data REST findAll with multiple Ids

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

Sorry if this sounds trivial. What is the URL for calling the following Spring DATA REST Repository  method: findAll(Iterable ids);

I tried:

```
    http://localhost:5000/book?ids=5450f92352d1d609c0c75291,5450f92352d1d609c0c75292
    http://localhost:5000/book/5450f92352d1d609c0c75291,5450f92352d1d609c0c75292
    http://localhost:5000/book/search/findAll?ids=5450f92352d1d609c0c75291,5450f92352d1d609c0c75292
```

The first one actually seems to return all books. The two last do not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass ?ids=21&ids=22 and receive a `List<Long> ids` on your controller.